# Typescript [ts] cannot find modules even if i was giving right path of typescript in import

Tags: angularjs, git, visual-studio-code

**event-component.ts**
 *EventService* is the service class *Injectable* but i have getting error [ts] cannot find module '/shared/event.service' but *app.module.ts* i was giving same path of this service it is working their. path is correct please tell me whats wrong in this..

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core'
        import { EventService } from '/shared/event.service'
        //[ts] Cannot find module '/shared/event.service'.

        @Component({
            selector: 'event-list',
            template: `<div><h2>we are using Angular Js 2</h2><hr/>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6"  *ngFor="let event of events">
                                <event-thumbnil [eventList] = "event" >
                                </event-thumbnil>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>`
        })

        export class EventsListComponent {
          events:any[]

          constructor(private eventService : EventService)
          {
            this.events= this.eventService.getEvents();
          }
        }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {EventsAppComponent } from './events-app.component'
import { EventsListComponent } from './Events/events-list.component'
import {EventThumbnilComponent } from './Events/events-list.thumbnil'
import {NavabarComponent} from './nav/navbar-component'
import {EventService} from './shared/event.service'

@NgModule({
 imports:[BrowserModule],
 declarations: [EventsAppComponent, EventsListComponent,EventThumbnilComponent,NavabarComponent],
 bootstrap:[EventsAppComponent],
 providers:[EventService]
})
export class AppModule{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your typescript file you forget to give the directory for you service

```
import {EventService} from '../shared/event.service'
```

check it out it may works